# Reactor/RxJava How do back pressure when reading from SQS

Tags: rx-java, project-reactor

I'm new to the whole reactive paradigm and I'm trying to understand how back pressure would work when reading from a queue like SQS.

In Reactor you'd have your Flux and in RxJava you'd have your Observable polling SQS in the background like:

```
while (true) {
   Future<ReceiveMessageResult> future = sqsClient.receiveMessageAsync(queueUrl);
   //emit or send to subscribers
}
```

Lets say you have a downstream component that needs to make REST call that is rate limited. How do you tell the poller to slow down due to a rate limit so you don't end up having a bunch of live messages sitting in memory with the potential to OOM?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this scenario, you need to use Flowable. With Flowable, subscriber can request for certain number of message at a time, after processing received message it requests for next batch.

Ref : https://medium.com/@srinuraop/rxjava-backpressure-3376130e76c1

```java
Flowable<Integer> observable = Flowable.range(1, 133);
observable.subscribe(new DefaultSubscriber<Integer>() {
    @Override public void onStart() {
        request(1);
    }
    @Override public void onNext(Integer t) {
        LOGGER.info("item "+t);
        //this where you request message, in this case one message at time 
        //and after processing one message it will request for next one.
        request(1);
    }
    @Override public void onError(Throwable t) {
        LOGGER.info(""+t);
    }
    @Override public void onComplete() {
        LOGGER.info("complete");
    }
});
```